# layout taking too much time to load android

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout is taking too much time to load approximately 2-3 seconds on actual device.My layout have lots of view ranging from 40-60 views. I am checking for various condtion as well in `OnCreate()`.So can anyone suggest me how can i load my activity faster. And most of the views have background image.In actuality my entire layout is full of `ImageView`.
Below is the code-snippet of the `onCreate()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fueladd_layout);

    face2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"digital.ttf");
    typewriter=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"veteran_typewriter.ttf");

    Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width=display.getWidth();
    height=display.getHeight();

    dbc=new Databaseconnection(this);
    sdb=dbc.getWritableDatabase();
    sdb=dbc.getReadableDatabase();

    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    fyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    date();


    mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.button_click);
    newcarmenu=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.newcarmenu);
    topmenu=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.topmenu);
    newnotelayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.newnotelayout);
    layout_mileage=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_mileage);

    img_tabdashboard=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_tabdashboard);
    img_tabdashboard.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_tabexpenses=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_tabexpenses);
    img_tabexpenses.setImageDrawable(img_tabexpenses.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabexpensespressed));
    img_tabexpenses.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_tabfinancial=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_tabfinancial);
    img_tabfinancial.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_tabtrip=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_tabtrip);
    img_tabtrip.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_menu=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_menu);
    img_menu.getLayoutParams().width=(int) (width*0.109375);
    img_menu.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_preferences=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_preferences);
    img_preferences.getLayoutParams().width=(int) (width*0.109375);
    img_preferences.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_mycar=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_mycar);
    img_mycar.setOnClickListener(this);

    imgnotesdone=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgnotesdone);
    imgnotesdone.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_aboutus=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_aboutus);
    img_aboutus.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_editcar=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_editcar);
    img_editcar.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_exit=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_exit);
    img_exit.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_fuel=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_fuel);
    img_fuel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fuel2);
    img_fuel.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_toll=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_toll);
    img_toll.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_parking=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_parking);
    img_parking.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_puc=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_puc);
    img_puc.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_oil=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_oil);
    img_oil.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_service=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_service);
    img_service.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_add=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_save);
    img_add.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_view=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
    img_view.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_addnewcar=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_addnewcar);
    img_addnewcar.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_addnewbike=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_addnewbike);
    img_addnewbike.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_usedcar=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_usedcar);
    img_usedcar.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_usedcar=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_usedbike);
    img_usedcar.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_menuexit=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_menuexit);
    img_menuexit.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_loc_picker = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_loc_picker);
    img_loc_picker.setOnClickListener(this);

    txt_title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
    txt_title.setTypeface(face2,Typeface.BOLD);
    txt_title.setText("FUEL");


    layout_list=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_list);

    animationBottomIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(layout_list.getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_up);
    animationBottomOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(layout_list.getContext(), R.anim.slide_out_down);

    animationRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(layout_list.getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_right);
    animationRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(layout_list.getContext(), R.anim.slide_out_right);


    list_type= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_type);
    list_type.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    list_location= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_location);
    list_location.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    txt_type_loc=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_type_loc);
    txt_type_loc.setTypeface(typewriter);

    img_arrow_down = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_arrow_down);
    img_arrow_down.setOnClickListener(this);

    txtselectdate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_currentdate);
    txtselectdate.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtnewnotes=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtnewnotes);
    txtnewnotes.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtcdate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcdate);
    txtcdate.setTypeface(typewriter);
    txtcdate.setOnClickListener(this);

    txtcurrentkm=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_currentkm);
    txtcurrentkm.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtpreviouskm=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_previouskm);
    txtpreviouskm.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtfuel=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_quantity);
    txtfuel.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtrate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_rate);
    txtrate.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtamount=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_amount);
    txtamount.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtmileage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_mileage);
    txtmileage.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtlocation=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
    txtlocation.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtbrand=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_brand);
    txtbrand.setTypeface(typewriter);

    txtnote=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_note);
    txtnote.setTypeface(typewriter);

    editbrand=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_brand);
    editbrand.setTypeface(typewriter);

    editlocation=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_location);
    editlocation.setTypeface(typewriter);

    editnewnotes=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnewnotes);
    editnewnotes.setTypeface(typewriter);

    img_date_picker = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_date_picker);
    img_date_picker.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_loc_picker = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_loc_picker);
    img_loc_picker.setOnClickListener(this);

    img_brand_picker = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_brand_picker);
    img_brand_picker.setOnClickListener(this);

    imgnotepicker = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imgnotepicker );
    imgnotepicker .setOnClickListener(this);

    //this will set the text of edit view
    //the 1st record value is retrived and displayed
    //if no record is present than editview is empty

    loc_select_Query = "select  item From FuelLocation";
    Cursor cursor_loc = sdb.rawQuery(loc_select_Query, null);
    int count=cursor_loc.getCount();
    cursor_loc.moveToFirst();
    if(count>1)
    {
        editlocation.setText(cursor_loc.getString(0));
    }

    //this will set the text of edit view of brand
    //the 1st record value is retrived and displayed
    //if no record is present than editview is empty

    brand_select_Query = "select  brand From FuelBrand";
    Log.i("select_Query", brand_select_Query);
    Cursor cursor_brand = sdb.rawQuery(brand_select_Query, null);
    int count1=cursor_brand.getCount();
    cursor_brand.moveToFirst();
    if(count1>1)
    {
        editbrand.setText(cursor_brand.getString(0));
    }

    editcurrentkm=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_currentkm);
    editcurrentkm.setTypeface(typewriter);

    editpreviouskm=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_previouskm);
    editpreviouskm.setTypeface(typewriter);
    editpreviouskm.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
        {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                String select="Select Fuel_CurrentKm from Fuel ";
                Cursor selectcur = sdb.rawQuery(select, null);
                selectcur.moveToLast();
                Log.i("Record Count",Integer.toString(selectcur.getCount()));

                if(selectcur.getCount()>0)
                {   
                    Log.i("currentkm",editcurrentkm.getText().toString());
                    Log.i("currentkm",editcurrentkm.getText().toString());
                    if(Integer.valueOf(editpreviouskm.getText().toString())<Integer.valueOf(selectcur.getString(0).toString()))
                    {
                        msg="Enter previous odometer greater than"+selectcur.getString(0).toString();
                        showToastMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    editcurrentkm.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
        {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                ckm=editcurrentkm.getText().toString();

                if(ckm.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                    msg="Enter Current Odometer reading";
                    showToastMessage(msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Integer.valueOf(editcurrentkm.getText().toString())>Integer.valueOf(editpreviouskm.getText().toString()))
                    {
                        if(pcount>1)
                        {
                            currentkm=Integer.valueOf(ckm);
                            calmileage=(currentkm-previouskm)/pquantity;
                            editmileage.setText(Float.toString(calmileage));
                            Log.i("Mileage",Float.toString(calmileage));
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        msg="Enter Current Odometer reading Greater than Previous Odometer reading";
                        showToastMessage(msg);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
    editfuel=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_quantity);
    editfuel.setTypeface(typewriter);

    editrate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_rate);
    editrate.setTypeface(typewriter);
    editrate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) 
        {
            if(!arg1)
            {
                if(!editfuel.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                    fquantity=editfuel.getText().toString();
                    quantity=Float.valueOf(fquantity);
                    if(!editrate.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {
                        frate=editrate.getText().toString();
                        total=quantity*Float.valueOf(frate);
                        editamount.setText(Float.toString(total));

                    }                       
                }   
            }
        }
    });

    editamount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_amount);
    editamount.setTypeface(typewriter);
    editamount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) 
        {
            if(!arg1)
            {
                if(!editfuel.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                    fquantity=editfuel.getText().toString();
                    quantity=Float.valueOf(fquantity);
                    if(!editamount.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {
                        famount=editamount.getText().toString();
                        rate=Float.valueOf(famount)/quantity;
                        editrate.setText(Float.toString(rate));
                    }                       
                }   
            }
        }
    });

    editmileage=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_mileage);
    editmileage.setTypeface(typewriter);

    editnote=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_note);
    editnote.setTypeface(typewriter);

    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    readsound=myPrefs.getBoolean(SOUND,sound);
    car_id= myPrefs.getInt(MY_CAR,count);
    Log.i("car id",Integer.toString(car_id));
    if(car_id==0)
    {
        car_id=1;
        Log.i("Car_ID",Long.toString(car_id));
    }

    Intent editintent=getIntent();
    String action=editintent.getAction();
    Log.i("Action",action);

    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.curioussolutions.autoistdiary.fuel.EDIT"))
    {
        Log.i("inside","edit");
        record=(Integer) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Id");
        Log.i("Record",Integer.toString(record));

        Cursor editcursor = sdb.rawQuery("select Fuel_Date,Fuel_CurrentKm,Fuel_PreviousKm,Fuel_Quantity,Fuel_Rate,Fuel_Amount,Fuel_Milege,Fuel_Brand,Fuel_Location,Fuel_Note from Fuel where Fuel_Id="+record, null);
        count=editcursor.getCount();

        editcursor.moveToFirst();

        udate=editcursor.getString(0).toString();
        Log.i("date",udate);
        txtcdate.setText(udate);
        Log.i("date",udate);

        currentkm=Integer.valueOf(editcursor.getString(1).toString());
        editcurrentkm.setText(Integer.toString(currentkm));
        Log.i("currentkm",Integer.toString(currentkm));

        pkm=Integer.valueOf(editcursor.getString(2).toString());
        Log.i("previouskm",Integer.toString(pkm));
        editpreviouskm.setText(Integer.toString(pkm));
        Log.i("previouskm",Integer.toString(pkm));

        quantity=Float.valueOf(editcursor.getString(3).toString());
        editfuel.setText(Float.toString(quantity));
        Log.i("quantity",Float.toString(quantity));

        rate=Float.valueOf(editcursor.getString(4).toString());
        editrate.setText(Float.toString(rate));
        Log.i("rate",Float.toString(rate));

        total=Float.valueOf(editcursor.getString(5).toString());
        editamount.setText(Float.toString(total));
        Log.i("cost",Float.toString(total));
        if(record>1)
        {
            calmileage=Float.valueOf(editcursor.getString(6).toString());
            editmileage.setText(Float.toString(calmileage));
            Log.i("mileage",Float.toString(calmileage));
        }
        if(record==1)
        {
            layout_mileage.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
        }
        location=editcursor.getString(7).toString();
        editlocation.setText(location);
        Log.i("location",location);

        fbrand=editcursor.getString(8).toString();
        editbrand.setText(fbrand);
        Log.i("date",fbrand);

        notes=editcursor.getString(9).toString();
        editnote.setText(notes);
        Log.i("notes",notes);
    }
    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.curioussolutions.autoistdiary.fuel.ADD"))
    {
        Log.i("inside","add");
        String select1="select Fuel_CurrentKm,Fuel_Quantity,Fuel_Rate from Fuel";
        Cursor cur = sdb.rawQuery(select1, null);
        pcount=cur.getCount()+1;
        cur.moveToLast();

        if(pcount>1)
        {   
            previouskm=Integer.valueOf(cur.getString(0).toString());
            pquantity=Float.valueOf(cur.getString(1).toString());
            rate=Float.valueOf(cur.getString(2).toString());
            editpreviouskm.setText(Integer.toString(previouskm));
            editrate.setText(Float.toString(rate));
        }
        else
        {
            layout_mileage.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
            editpreviouskm.setText("0");
        }
        date();
        txtcdate.setText(date);

    }
    else
    {
        layout_mileage.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
        editpreviouskm.setText("0");
        date();
        txtcdate.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to see where the time is going.  I just put some log prints in as they get time-stamped.

Comment: @Ifor where did u put the log prints ?

Comment: Very start of onCreate, after the supper call, before and after anything I may thing is slow. In OnResume start and End. There is a callback once the activity is displayed I don't remember off hand but in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really good explanation how can you optimize your UI so it can load faster : [Android Performance in Practice by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/06/android-performance-in-practice/).
I suggest you to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use threads or if it is not possible watch if in your method, OnCreate, is there a call to something that consume resources before the layout to be complete rendered.

Comment: yeah i do have call to shared preferences and i load animation and along with it couple of sounds.doing some date related calculations and database coding

Answer (score 0):

Let the onCreateComplete as quickly as possible. do not hold it for loading your views.
Start AsyncTasks to load the views in findViewById.
then in asyntasks onPostsExecute you may set values to your views e.g setting images to your imageviews etc.

worth a try.

Comment: i would definitely give it a try. can u suggest me what part of code should i put it in the asynctask ?

Comment: can u help me with examples on this. i am quite new to this stuff,though i read loads of stuff most of the examples are for displaying progress of either loading a file from internet or something related to  it. and along with the loading of images i have database and reading of shared preference as well. any help regarding this would be really appreciated and would do really good to me